# Couldn't open socket connection to server. Error (110): Connection timed out

Tags: php, xml, codeigniter, nusoap

I have the following Webservice which is a third-party WS:

```
(http:// host:453/INTEGRA/WSRG001.pgm?xml=(PAIS)GT(/PAIS)(ORDEN)JZ9000104(/ORDEN)(TIPO)2(/TIPO)(NUMERO)P734FPS(/NUMERO)) using this tags "<>"
```

host: 200.114.117.11

It needs to send the parameters by xml or nusoap.

I have the following code as well:

```
$server = new nusoap_client('http://200.114.117.11:453/INTEGRA/WSRG001.pgm?xml',false);

print_r($server);

$request = array(
               array(
                       array('PAIS' => 'GT'),
                       'STRUCT'
                    ),
               array(
                       array('id_number' => '123'),
                       'STRUCT'
                    )
           );

$row =  $server->call('ORDENTALLER',$orden);
if ($server->fault) {
    echo 'Fault'. print_r($result);
} else {
    // Check for errors
    $err = $server->getError();
    if ($err) {
        // Display the error
        echo 'Error'. $err;
    } else {
        // Display the result
        echo 'Result' . print_r($row);
    }
}
```

I'm getting:

> ErrorHTTP Error: Couldn't open socket connection to server Http// 200.114.117.11:453 / INTEGRA/WSRG001.pgm?xml, Error (110): Connection timed out

Any idea why this is not working? I'm working on CodeIgniter, by the way.

Comment: Well it could be that the connection is just timing out. But it also looks like your parameter encoding and the URL youre using for the soap client are likely incorrect... I would either expect the `?xml` to be on the URL with some sort of value, or i would expect it encoded as part of the SOAP parameters with the request. It looks like you may be trying ot mix and match here. But Thats a guess because you havent given us any details on the service you are trying to hit. If you can post a link to its documentation or the relevant details directly in your question we might be able to help.

Comment: @prodigitalson Sure, what details will be usefull for you?

Comment: The example XML and parameters from the documentation for the specific SOAP call you are trying to make... leaving out any API crednetials or anything like that of course.

Comment: http://200.114.117.11:453/INTEGRA/WSRG001.pgm?xml=<PAIS>GT</PAIS><ORDEN>JZ9000104</ORDEN><TIPO>2</TIPO><NUMERO>P734FPS</NUMERO>

Comment: @prodigitalson I posted the URL where you can find the XML

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow Port 453 for what you want, allow this port in your firewall

I hope this will help you into the right direction